# jQuery tooltip show loading gif while ajax gets data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a list of items that users can trigger a tooltip if desired. I am trying to show a loading gif while the ajax call is performed to get the appropriate data in the tooltip window.

How can I achieve this?

```
$(document).tooltip({
  items:'.tooltip',
  tooltipClass:'toolTipDetails',
  position: { my: "left+5 top", at: "right center" }
  content:function(callback) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');

      $.get('tickets/tooltips.php', {
        id:id
      }, function(data) {
        callback(data); 
    });
},
```

Comment: Show an image before the AJAX request is made, and hide it again when it completes.

Answer (score 2):

Add an Image loader (hidden by default) to your page e.g :

```
<img src="loader.gif" id="loader" style="display:none"/>
```

Then you could toogle it using jQuery functions `show()/hide()` like:

```
$(document).tooltip({
  items:'.tooltip',
  tooltipClass:'toolTipDetails',
  position: { my: "left+5 top", at: "right center" }
  content:function(callback) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');

      $('#loader').show(); // <------ Show loader

      $.get('tickets/tooltips.php', {
        id:id
      }, function(data) {
        $('#loader').hide(); // <------ Hide loader
        callback(data); 
    });
},
```